Unhandled exception while executing module: The term 'Resolve-ExecutablePath' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
I am new to Ansible and running EXE as windows service using ansible.windows.win_command.
Task:
- name: Register as windows service
  ansible.windows.win_command: 
    cmd: sc.exe create "{{otelservicename}}" start= auto binpath= "\"{{otelcollectorexe}}\" --config \"{{otelconfigurationfile}}\""
  register: create_command_info

But when execute, it is throwing the an error

An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full
traceback, use -vvv. The error was: at , : line
71 fatal: [xx.xx.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg":
"Unhandled exception while executing module: The term
'Resolve-ExecutablePath' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again."}

Ansible version: 2.9.27

having exactly same situation while using ansible.windws.win_powershell
executable: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe

while it is present in documentation https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_powershell_module.html#parameter-executable
